# Why is Touchable Opacity not working on android?

Tags: android, react-native, touchableopacity

The touchable opacity is working perfectly on IOS, but it is not working on android.

`TouchableOpacity` is being imported from `react-native`

My code :

```
    <View style = { styles.view}>
                         
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button}  onPress={() => this.props.play}>
            <Text style = { styles.buttonText}>Play</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
```

My stylesheet:

```
button:{
        backgroundColor : '#2F2440',
        padding : 10,
        borderRadius : 10,
        marginTop :  RFValue(305),
        marginLeft : RFValue(20),
        marginRight : RFValue(30),
        width : RFValue(200),
        height : RFValue(40),
        alignSelf : 'baseline',  
    },
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? We need more information

Comment: From where are you importing `TouchableOpacity`? `react-native-gesture-handler` or `react-native`?

Comment: What's mean `this.props.play` called in `onpress`?! , I Think You Should Call Function there, for test Your button Work Correctly , add `Console.log("test");` and check that's Called or not.

Comment: When I touch on the touchable opacity, it is simply not being pressed.

Comment: `TouchableOpacity` is being imported from `react-native`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `onPress={() => this.props.play}`

with `onPress={() => this.props.play()}` or this `onPress={this.props.play}`

Comment: Okay, can you confirm if this.props.play() indeed works by calling it outside and not on a click or press? After the component is mounted  maybe?

Comment: Also, as suggested by @Meisam Saba, does console.log print anything?

Comment: @Meisam Saba,console.log did print "test".

Comment: then can you try my suggestion of calling this.props.play() in other place and see if it actually works?

Comment: Can you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: you could call `this.props.play()` within the constructor and see if it actually does what the function is supposed to do. Maybe add a few console.logs within play() definition